# Web Performance: How to Flush / Stream HTML Document with NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, performance, web-performance

Let's say we are using server-side rendering for a website.

The website has a static header, but for the body we need to fetch a product list from a 3rd party.

Let's say fetching the product list takes 500ms.

Instead of constructing the complete html file on the server (takes > 500ms) and only then sending the html file to the client, we want to start streaming the header immediately. Because the browser can parse html files [incrementally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/How_browsers_work#:%7E:text=Even%20if%20the%20request%20page%27s%20HTML%20is%20larger%20than%20the%20initial%2014KB%20packet%2C%20the%20browser%20will%20begin%20parsing%20and%20attempting%20to%20render%20an%20experience%20based%20on%20the%20data%20it%20has), the user should be able to see the header even before the list has been fetched on the server (Let's assume the website has no CSS and no JS).

Ilya Grigorik describes this approach in more detail [here](https://youtu.be/PkOBnYxqj3k?t=467).

How would a basic version of this look like in NodeJS?

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184103/how-to-flush-chunks-of-arbitrary-sizes-in-nodejs